# UITableView Frame is not fitting on self.view when i tapped on Button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am beginner in iOS and in my project I have create One UITableView and I have added here headerview for TableList and inside of headerView I have added one UILabel and one UIbutton ok that's fine

And when I load tableList I am loading headerView "label" text is empty and when I tapped on button which was added on my tableList headerView then I am loading UIlabel text as something in my Button action

My main problem is when I load tableList at firstTime TableList is fitting perfectly as like my below "first image" and when I tapped on button then tableList is not fitting perfectly as like my second image. Why tableList frame is changing?

### My code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    UILabel *label;
    NSArray * mainArray;
    NSString * HeaderlabelText;
    UIView * ContentView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self createTableList];
}

-(void)createTableList{

    [MaintableView removeFromSuperview];
    MaintableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //MaintableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    MaintableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    MaintableView.dataSource=self;
    MaintableView.delegate=self;
    MaintableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [MaintableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:MaintableView];

mainArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

}

//Delegate methods:-

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return mainArray.count;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 300, 30)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    UIView *bgview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgview;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sectio{
    return 50;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 30.0f)];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 50, 20)];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    lbl.text = HeaderlabelText;
    [view addSubview:lbl];

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
               action:@selector(PopOverAction:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Show View1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 5, 50, 30);
    [view addSubview:button1];

    return view;
}

- (void)PopOverAction:(id)sender{

    HeaderlabelText = @"Section1";
    [self createTableList];
}
```

### firstimage:

[image]

### secondimage:

[image]

Comment: Hi @AbhiRam why did you recreate your tableView after tap ?

Comment: because i am assign HeaderView  text after tapped on button

Comment: and moreever with out recreate my tableList headerview text not assinging and if thre is any better way please tell me

Comment: Do you have only one header in you tableView or one header for each section ?

Comment: @TheRonin why this problem is coming?

Comment: why do you creating the table view in each tap?

Answer (score 1):

There is a best way to do what you want.

This method `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` is used to setup one header for each section. I think you need to remove it.

You want one header for all you tableView. So create a custom `UIVIew` variable (`self.headerView`) you can retain in your ViewController (the view currently created in `viewForHeaderInSection` method).

After that create a method like `upadateHeaderView` that update the label of your header. Call this method in your button action method (and not recreate tableView).

To finish when you create your tableView (only once) call `[tableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];`in your `-(void)createTableList` method. Now you have one header for all your tableView.

So you need to create a customView. Here an example header:

```
@interface CustomView : UIVIew

@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;

@end
```

And your viewController become like this :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){

    UILabel *label;
    NSArray * mainArray;
    NSString * HeaderlabelText;
    UIView * ContentView;
    CustomView *headerView;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createHeader];
    [self createTableList];
}

-(void)createTableList{

    MaintableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    MaintableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    MaintableView.dataSource=self;
    MaintableView.delegate=self;
    MaintableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [MaintableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [MaintableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
    [self.view addSubview:MaintableView];

    mainArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

}

- (void)createHeaderView {
    self.headerView = [CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 30.0f)];
    [self.headerView.button addTarget:self
                               action:@selector(PopOverAction:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //Setup your customView HERE
}

- (void)updateHeader {
    //Update self.headerView HERE
    [self.headerView.label setText:HeaderlabelText];
}
//Delegate methods:-

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return mainArray.count;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [MaintableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 300, 30)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.text = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    UIView *bgview = [[UIView alloc] init];
    bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgview;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
- (void)PopOverAction:(id)sender{

    HeaderlabelText = @"Section1";
    [self updateHeader];
}
```